# How to pythonically set a symbol as an ascii character (Font Marker) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I need to set a point on a map as an ASCII symbol with python.

I'd like to do this in a rule based renderer.

something like:

```
rule.setSymbolAsFontMarker("✫")
```

So I'd have something like this in my existing code:

```
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
rule.setSymbolAsFontMarker("✫")
rule.setScaleMinDenom(70000)
rule.setScaleMaxDenom(1000000) 
root_rule.appendChild(rule)
## delete the default rule
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
## apply the renderer to the layer
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

Any guidance is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This code works for a single symbol renderer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
properties = {'name': "✫"}
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symbol)
symbol_layer = QgsFontMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(properties)
renderer.symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

If you want a rule based renderer, you need to use `QgsRuleBasedRendererV2`

[Here](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) is a nice post. Scroll down to "Rule-based renderer".

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this with properties = {'name': "*"} but I only get a blank symbol (default circle maker)?

Comment: Probably something with encoding. It works on my Debian Qgis 2.12 and display this star.

Comment: Solved encoding with: `properties = {'chr': u'✫','color':'#000000','size':'7'}`